# SQL Multiple Row Insert w/ multiple selects from different tables

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to do a multiple insert based on values that I am pulling from a another table. Basically I need to give all existing users access to a service that previously had access to a different one. Table1 will take the data and run a job to do this.

```
   INSERT INTO Table1 (id, serv_id, clnt_alias_id, serv_cat_rqst_stat)
SELECT
  (SELECT Max(id) + 1
     FROM Table1 ),
  '33', --The new service id
  clnt_alias_id,
  'PI' --The code to let the job know to grant access
FROM TABLE2,
WHERE serv_id = '11' --The old service id
```

I am getting a Primary key constraint error on id.

Please help.

Thanks,
Colin

Comment: Don't do `select max(id)+1`. Just make ID an auto_increment primary key and let mysql generate the values for you. This code is subject to race conditions and nothing will prevent other parallel queries from getting the **SAME** max(id) value and generating duplicate ids.

Comment: I do not have access to change that parameter of the table and the request for that change would take much longer that the deadline to get these entries set up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This query is impossible. The max(id) sub-select will evaluate only ONCE and return the same value for all rows in the parent query:

```
MariaDB [test]> create table foo (x int);
MariaDB [test]> insert into foo values (1), (2), (3);
MariaDB [test]> select *, (select max(x)+1 from foo) from foo;
+------+----------------------------+
| x    | (select max(x)+1 from foo) |
+------+----------------------------+
|    1 |                          4 |
|    2 |                          4 |
|    3 |                          4 |
+------+----------------------------+
3 rows in set (0.04 sec)
```

You will have to run your query multiple times, once for each record you're trying to copy. That way the max(id) will get the ID from the previous query.

Answer (score 0):

Is there a requirement that Table1.id be incremental ints? If not, just add the clnt_alias_id to Max(id). This is a nasty workaround though, and you should really try to get that column's type changed to auto_increment, like Marc B suggested.